# C# wpf wont refresh using array binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a simple Ellispis on a wpf that I bind to an Array item "Data[0]" to animate it.
Issue is that when I bind it to that array, and its value toggle "true/false" there is no impact on the UI.

But when I change the binding to another public bool from the same class. No problem

```
<Ellipse Width="19"
Height="18"
Margin="29,137,0,0"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Fill="{Binding Data[0], 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBrushConverter}, 
    Mode=OneWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Stroke="Black" />
```

When I bind to that Array, no update on the UI:

```
    public bool[] Data
    {
        get{ return _data; }
        set{ _data= value; }
    }
    private bool[] _data= new Boolean[20];
```

When I do the binding to that bool, it is working:

```
    public bool DataSimple
    {
        get { return _dataSimple; }
        set { _dataSimple=value; }
    }
    private bool _dataSimple;
```

This is used to refresh the values and control that it reached and both are showing good result in Debug:

```
    private void RefreshData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _data= _process.DataRes;
        _dataSimple= _process.DataRes[0];
        Debug.WriteLine(_data[0]);
        Debug.WriteLine(_dataSimple);
    }
```

Can someone try help me on this ?
thanks

Comment: It looks to me like it's because you're binding to the bool array index 0, not to the bool array itself (which has the getter/setter).  Try creating a BooleanArrayToBrushConverter, where you take just the first element and return its Brush.  Then, change your binding to `Fill="{BInding Data, Converter={StaticResource BooleanArrayToBrushConverter},".  I'm also confused as to how any of this is working without an INotifyPropertyChanged, but I digress.

Comment: By toggle i meant "value =  not value" switch from "true to false" or "false to true". I am real new on C#. But with all your comment I did it. Instead of using array i used ObservableCollection i binded it to a custome class and also added INotifyPropertyChanged then it worked. I need to read more about it cause it work but it is not clear in my mind how all behave and interact. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear as to exactly what you're changing and expecting to trigger an update to the user interface.

If you're updating individual bool values, then replace `bool[]` with `ObservableCollection<bool>` and initialise it with the appropriate number of items.

If you're supplying a whole new array of bool values then your classes need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the updated properties.